# Parallel.ForEach stalled when integrated with BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I adopted my implementation of parallel/consumer based on the code in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/is-this-a-valid-producer-consumer-implementation-for-parallel-processing-in-th)

```
class ParallelConsumer<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly int _maxParallel;
    private readonly Action<T> _action;
    private readonly TaskFactory _factory = new TaskFactory();
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _entries = new BlockingCollection<T>();
    private Task _task;

    public ParallelConsumer(int maxParallel, Action<T> action)
    {
        _maxParallel = maxParallel;
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _task = _factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(
                        _entries.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
                        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxParallel, CancellationToken = _tokenSource.Token },
                        (item, loopState) =>
                        {
                            Log("Taking" + item);
                            if (!_tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                _action(item);
                                Log("Finished" + item);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log("Not Taking" + item);
                                _entries.CompleteAdding();
                                loopState.Stop();
                            }
                        });
                },
                _tokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oce);
        }
    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T entry)
    {
        Log("Enqueuing" + entry);
        _entries.Add(entry);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_task == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _tokenSource.Cancel();
        while (!_task.IsCanceled)
        {
        }

        _task.Dispose();
        _tokenSource.Dispose();
        _task = null;
    }
}
```

And here is a test code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestRepeatedEnqueue(100, 1);
    }

    private static void TestRepeatedEnqueue(int itemCount, int parallelCount)
    {
        bool[] flags = new bool[itemCount];
        var consumer = new ParallelConsumer<int>(parallelCount,
                                              (i) =>
                                              {
                                                  flags[i] = true;
                                              }
            );
        consumer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            consumer.Enqueue(i);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Debug.Assert(flags.All(b => b == true));



    }
}
```

The test always fails - it always stuck at around 93th-item from the 100 tested. Any idea which part of my code caused this issue, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `Parallel.Foreach()` with `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`, as you have discovered.

For an explanation, see this blog post:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/

Excerpt from the blog:

> BlockingCollection’s GetConsumingEnumerable implementation is using BlockingCollection’s internal synchronization which already supports multiple consumers concurrently, but ForEach doesn’t know that, and its enumerable-partitioning logic also needs to take a lock while accessing the enumerable.
>
> As such, there’s more synchronization here than is actually necessary, resulting in a potentially non-negligable performance hit.
>
> [Also] the partitioning algorithm employed by default by both Parallel.ForEach and PLINQ use chunking in order to minimize synchronization costs: rather than taking the lock once per element, it'll take the lock, grab a group of elements (a chunk), and then release the lock.
>
> While this design can help with overall throughput, for scenarios that are focused more on low latency, that chunking can be prohibitive.

That blog also provides the source code for a method called `GetConsumingPartitioner()` which you can use to solve the problem.

```
public static class BlockingCollectionExtensions
{

    public static Partitioner<T> GetConsumingPartitioner<T>(this BlockingCollection<T> collection)
    {
        return new BlockingCollectionPartitioner<T>(collection);
    }


    public class BlockingCollectionPartitioner<T> : Partitioner<T>
    {
        private BlockingCollection<T> _collection;

        internal BlockingCollectionPartitioner(BlockingCollection<T> collection)
        {
            if (collection == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

            _collection = collection;
        }

        public override bool SupportsDynamicPartitions
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override IList<IEnumerator<T>> GetPartitions(int partitionCount)
        {
            if (partitionCount < 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("partitionCount");

            var dynamicPartitioner = GetDynamicPartitions();
            return Enumerable.Range(0, partitionCount).Select(_ => dynamicPartitioner.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
        }

        public override IEnumerable<T> GetDynamicPartitions()
        {
            return _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. Anyway, when I test further, the code in my OP does not fail when the number of item is a member of this sequence, [A200672](http://oeis.org/A200672) e.g. 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 29, 37, 45, 61, 77, 93, ... Any idea why? just curious.

Comment: @user69715 That's the sort of weird behaviour I found when I tried to do a similar thing. I guess it's just some weird interaction between Parallel.ForEach() and the underlying BlockingCollection, but I can't really explain it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for failure is because of the following reason as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208330/why-does-iterating-over-getconsumingenumerable-not-fully-empty-the-underlying)

> The partitioning algorithm employed by default by both
>   Parallel.ForEach and PLINQ use chunking in order to minimize
>   synchronization costs: rather than taking the lock once per element,
>   it'll take the lock, grab a group of elements (a chunk), and then
>   release the lock.

To get it to work, you can add a method on your `ParallelConsumer<T>` class to indicate that the adding is completed, as below

```
    public void StopAdding()
    {
        _entries.CompleteAdding();
    }
```

And now call this method after your `for loop` , as below

```
        consumer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            consumer.Enqueue(i);
        }
        consumer.StopAdding();
```

Otherwise, `Parallel.ForEach()` would wait for the threshold to be reached so as to grab the chunk and start processing.

Comment: the thing is in the production, the tasks get queued continuosly, so marking "StopAdding" does not help. Thanks for your answer, +1, but I'll go with the other answer.

Comment: Oops, looks like I can't +1 yet