# Limit the number of consumers for a queue who are running parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, queue, threadpool

I am using a queue, there are two threads. One is for Enqueue, the other is for Dequeue. Which are called as producer and consumer respectively. Produce can be unlimited. But I need to limit the consumers running at the same time. I read about “Task Parallel Library” and “Parallel.For”. But I’m not sure about the way that I should implement them here. Please advise me. Here are some of code segments for you to having a better understanding of the question

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

// The Producer code comes here
// ...

// The Consumer code comes here
Thread consumer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PendingBookingConsumer));
consumer.Start();
}

private static void PendingBookingConsumer()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (pendingBookingsQueue != null && pendingBookingsQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                PendingBooking oPendingBooking = pendingBookingsQueue.Dequeue();

                //Run the Console App
                string command = @"C:\ServerAgentConsole.exe";
                string args = oPendingBooking.Id + " " + oPendingBooking.ServiceAccountEmail.Trim() + " " + oPendingBooking.ServiceAccountPassword.Trim() + " " + oPendingBooking.ServiceAccountEmail.Trim()
                    + " " + oPendingBooking.MailBoxOwnerEmail.Trim() + " " + oPendingBooking.Method.Trim();

                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Process myProcess = (Process)sender;
                    Console.WriteLine("Agent for booking ID :" + myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments[0] + " Done");
                };

                process.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(2);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use one of the common techniques to process a `BlockingCollection` with a fixed degree of parallelism.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828518/parallel-foreach-stalled-when-integarated-with-blockingcollection) Specify the DOP in the `Parallel.ForEach` options.

Then, make the processing function wait for the child process:

```
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

That way you have a fixed number of child processes outstanding at any time.

Answer (score 0):

BlockingCollection supports an upper bound

[BlockingCollection Constructor (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267301(v=vs.110).aspx)

As Hans commented this is just size of collection.
Maybe you can do this with parallel in the consumer.

Comment: That's for the bounded *size* of the collection, it has nothing to do with the number of consumer threads.

Comment: @HansPassant OK.   Will delete when it gets an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider the [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) library, with easy implementation for `Producer/Consumer` pattern:

```
private static BufferBlock<int> m_buffer = new BufferBlock<int>>(
    new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 10, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 });

// Producer
private static async void Producer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        await m_buffer.SendAsync(Produce());
    }
}

// Consumer
private static async Task Consumer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Process(await m_buffer.ReceiveAsync());
    }
}
```

You can see the `BoundedCapacity` used for the throttling technique, limiting the queue size, and `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is used for the limiting the parallel consuming tasks.

You can download [introduction to `TPL Dataflow` from MSDN here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782).

PS: [How to: Implement a Producer-Consumer Dataflow Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601.aspx) on MSDN