# How does the Parallel.ForEach/For call the BlockingCollection.Take? with or without CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach, blockingcollection, cancellationtokensource

```
 try
 {
     ParallelOptions Options = new ParallelOptions();
     Options.CancellationToken = base.DownloadCancellation.Token;
     Parallel.ForEach(base.BlockingCollection1, Options, ActiveSeeder =>
         {
             //...
         });
 }
 catch
 {
     if (base.DownloadCancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
         return false;
 }
```

Does the `Parallel.ForEach`/`For` call the `BlockingCollection1.Take` function with or without the `CancellationToken` I put into the `ParallelOptions`?

Is there any chance to find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach()` does *not* call `Take()` at all, so your question is invalid.

Instead, it will treat the collection like any other `IEnumerable<T>`, which means it will call its `GetEnumerator()` and then work with the result. [What `GetEnumerator()` does for `BlockingCollection` is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267242.aspx):

> Unlike `GetConsumingEnumerable`, `BlockingCollection<T>.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` returns a standard enumerator that does not modify the underlying collection. If other threads are adding or removing elements concurrently when `GetEnumerator` is called, then the elements returned by the enumerator might not represent the current state of the collection.

If you want to remove items from the collection as you iterate, you could use `GetConsumingEnumerable()`, which does have [an overload that takes `CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395014.aspx). But this won't actually work very well, so it's better to use [`GetConsumingPartitioner()` from ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/) ([code on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/csharp/parallel/ParallelExtensionsExtras/Extensions/BlockingCollectionExtensions.cs)).

Comment: The link to `GetConsumingPartitioner` is now dead.  :(

Comment: @Vaccano Thanks for letting me know, I have updated the link.

Comment: Things have changed since this answer was published. Nowadays the best way to consume a `BlockingCollection<T>` with `Parallel.ForEach` is: `Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering), ...` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208330/why-does-iterating-over-getconsumingenumerable-not-fully-empty-the-underlying/33901522#33901522 "Why does iterating over GetConsumingEnumerable() not fully empty the underlying blocking collection").